# NullPointerException when rotating android (display changes size)

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm working with android & canvas, my code works flawlessly for other than when the display resolution changes (ie. rotating the device) the app forcecloses and log cat shows:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-367
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at ...doDraw()

The line it links the error to contains:

```
canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
```

But I believe it doesn't matter as long as it's trying to draw something and shows the first thing I'm trying to draw.

Here's my run loop:

```
        @Override
    public void run() {
        while (mPlaying) {
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    if (mPlaying == true) updatePosition();
                    doDraw(c);
                }
        } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Which I took directly from the LunarLander example. Now the crash doesn't happen every time I rotate, but about 75% of the time.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: When you rotate your screen, your actiity is destroyed, and the `onCreate()` is called again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help you

```
           if your android:targetSdkVersion="12" or less
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

      if your  android:targetSdkVersion="13" or more
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem for me. The correct format however was `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: doesn't help me. My android:targetSdkVersion="15"  and have android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize in my manifest, but the app produces an exception pretty much whenever I rotate my display...

Comment: There may be another problem.see your logcat to find it out.

Comment: You better fix your NPE than switch to configChanges hack